# MooTools fade in / fade out effect on a table

Tags: javascript, mootools

I am using MooTools library. I want my fade in fade out effect on table id

`<table id="myId"></table>`

i have working click event

```
aNextCal.addEvent('click',function(){
    //Click Event working here i want fade in fadeout code 
    this.showNextWeek();
}.bind(this));`
```

Please suggest

Comment: anyone have any idea??

Answer (score 2):

There is the default fade function to every element

```
document.id('myId').fade('out'); //hide
document.id('myId').fade('in'); //show
```

If you need something more complex to control the effect use [Tween](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Fx/Fx.Tween):

```
new Fx.Tween('myId', {
    duration: 4000,
    property: 'opacity',
    onComplete: function(){
         alert('hide');   
    }
}).start(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Mootools has a method [fade](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Fx/Fx.Tween#Element%3afade), which is intended for fading elements in/out.

```
myElement.fade([how]);
```

how = ('in', 'out', 'show', 'hide', 'toggle', number)

Example of use:

```
// simple example
$('myId').fade('out');

// setting up element with options
$('myId').set( 'tween', { 
    duration: 400,
    transition: 'quad:out'
});

$('myButton').addEvent('click', function(){
    $('myId').fade( 'toggle' );
});
```